# In testrail API how do I get project_id from case data?

Tags: testrail

I am trying to add a run with the add_run endpoint, but in my automation code I only have the test cases ids but not the project id (which according the the docs is mandatory).
Right now I am doing:

1. get all projects with /get_projects
2. get all cases /get_cases/{project_id}
   Then I loop over the cases I get and add the project_id to the case so I could create an add_run with the proper project_id.

This seems like the wrong way to do it.
Anybody has a better solution?
Also is there a way to create a run without a project_id? for example if I have a sanity run that includes cases from many projects.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to get the parent project ID:

1. get the case by ID and capture value of the `suite_id` field
2. get the parent suite by the value of the `suite_id` field and capture value of the `project_id` field <--- here you have your project ID and can use it for creating runs.